# DFS Doesn't Traverse The All Nodes (C language)

Tags: c, function, depth-first-search

This is my DFS function:

```
void DFS(int v, int *visited, int A[20][20],int satir){
    printf("\n%d visited",v+1);
    // Create a queue to store nodes to visit
    int i;
    // Mark the start node as visited and enqueue it
    visited[v] = 1;
    // While there are nodes in the queue
    for(i=0;i<satir;i++){
        if (A[v][i]==1 && visited[i]==0){
            DFS(i,visited,A,satir);
        }
    }
}
```

This is how i call it:
DFS(0,&visited,Tmp,satir/2);

And this is my adjacency matrix:

```
{0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0},
{0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0}
```

And my output:

> 1 visited
> 2 visited
> 5 visited
> 6 visited
> 8 visited
> 7 visited

Can you tell me why it doesn't traverse the all nodes. Everything looks perfect but it doesn't

Comment: please post the full example, including the code you use to call your function.

Comment: ... especially the declarations and values of the caller's `visited`, `Tmp`, and `satir` variables.

Comment: BFS uses a stack, not a queue. DFS uses a queue. Your code doesn't have a queue but the comments allude to one. `&visited` is most likely an error, and if you replace your dynamic memory allocation with a global array, `&visited` is still an error.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed. visited array was defined by dynamic memory allocation. Instead of it, I defined it as a global array. It's working now!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).